# Regular expression to split string at '/' or '\' in javascript?

Tags: javascript, split

I'm using the javascript's method "split()" to split a string at '\' or '/' characters. I searched some other posts to see how regular expressions work and tried this:

```
var text1 = "some/text";
var text2 = "some\\text2"
var words = text1.split(/\//);
var words2 = text2.split(/\\/);
```

Both work great, but When I try this one:

```
var text3 = "some\\other/text";
var words3 = text3.split(/\////);
```

It just don't work. I don't know what I'm missing here.

Comment: Stackoverflow's syntax highlighting should be a hint for why your version is not working :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex you want is

```
/[\/\\]/
```

The `[]` means "one of these characters", `\/` represents a forward slash and `\\` represents a backward slash. Since `\` and `/` are special characters in regular expressions, I had to escape them by escaping them with a preceding backslash.